# SQLite3 not setting field's value to the specified value

Tags: python, database, sqlite, discord.py

So, I'm making a discord bot, and I wanted to add a leveling system, but it just doesn't work (I'm getting no errors). Here's the problem: Whenever I level up, I don't. What I mean is that when I level up, it says: "@Crabby has reached level 2, GG!" but when I look at the database I was level 1. It did reset the exp though, but that just makes it more confusing as to why the level up part isn't working. Anyway, here's the code:

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        # Role variables
        lvl_5_role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='Memeling (Level 5+)')
        lvl_10_role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='Memer (Level 10+)')
        lvl_15_role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='Ultimate Memer (Level 15+)')
        # Checking if the author is not a bot (This prevents a loop)
        if not message.author.bot:
            # Database variables
            db = sqlite3.connect('database\main.sqlite3')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id FROM levels WHERE guild_id = '{message.guild.id}' and user_id = '{message.author.id}'")
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            #  End of primary variables
            if result is None:
                sql = ("INSERT INTO levels(guild_id, user_id, exp, lvl) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)")
                val = (message.guild.id, message.author.id, 10, 0)
                cursor.execute(sql, val)
                db.commit()
            else:
                cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id, exp, lvl FROM levels WHERE guild_id = '{message.guild.id}' and user_id = '{message.author.id}'")
                result1 = cursor.fetchone()
                exp = int(result1[1])
                sql = ("UPDATE levels SET exp = ? WHERE guild_id = ? and user_id = ?")
                val = (exp + random.randint(1, 5), str(message.guild.id), str(message.author.id))
                cursor.execute(sql, val)
                db.commit()

                cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id, exp, lvl FROM levels WHERE guild_id = '{message.guild.id}' and user_id = '{message.author.id}'")
                result2 = cursor.fetchone()

                xp_start = int(result2[1])
                lvl_start = int(result2[2])
                xp_end = math.floor(5 * (lvl_start ^ 2) + 50 * lvl_start + 100)

                if xp_end < xp_start:
                    await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} has reached level {lvl_start + 1}, GG!")
                    
                    if lvl_start == 5:
                        message.author.add_roles(lvl_5_role)
                    elif lvl_start == 10:
                        message.author.add_roles(lvl_10_role)
                    elif lvl_start == 15:
                        message.author.add_roles(lvl_15_role)
                    sql = "UPDATE levels SET lvl = ? and user_id = ?"
                    val = str(lvl_start + 1), str(message.author.id)
                    cursor.execute(sql, val)
                    db.commit()
                    sql = "UPDATE levels SET exp = ? and guild_id = ? and user_id = ?"
                    val = 0, str(message.guild.id), str(message.author.id)
                    cursor.execute(sql, val)
                    db.commit()
                    cursor.close()
                    db.close()
        # if the author is a bot
        else:
            pass
```

NOTE: I am using Python 3.8.6 and discord.py rewrite

EDIT: I've narrowed the code down to the on_message() listener since I think that is where the issue is. Also, I have tested it, and it does properly level me up from level 0 to level 1, but after that, it doesn't level me up at all when I get enough XP for the level up, but it still resets my XP to 0

EDIT 2: I added a condition to the exp reset and level up queries but they still don't work

Comment: Could you post a code sample that concentrates on your question, instead of pasting your entire code? i.e., write a code sample *from scratch* that reproduces the issue you see.

Comment: To clarify, the issue has nothing to do with your bot, or how it is supposed to work, but with SQLite not saving a value you would expect it to save. In fact, any code that relates to Discord at all has nothing to do with your question and should be removed because it is a distraction. Isolate the issue.

Comment: That being said, have a very close look on the SQL here. `sql = "UPDATE levels SET lvl = ? and user_id = ?"`.

Comment: @Tomalak I don't see anything wrong with the statement, and yes, I already knew it had nothing to do with the discord.py package

Comment: If you don't see anything wrong with the statement, look again. After fixing the SQL syntax error it contains, state in plain words what it's supposed to be doing, and ask yourself if it is really doing that. The following statement has the same problem. If you're still unsure, execute the statements in something like DB Browser for SQLite and see what they to.

Comment: Your code suffers from not being DRY ("don't repeat yourself" is a fundamental paradigm in programming). You've copypasted SQL to "fetch user details" and "set user details" all over the place. Don't do that. Write exactly one (!) function that fetches user data from the DB, and exactly one (!) function that saves user data in the DB. Replace all the current duplication with calls to those two functions.

Comment: @Tomalak here's the result when running it in DB Browser: Execution finished without errors.
Result: query executed successfully. Took 0ms, 0 rows affected
At line 1:
UPDATE levels SET lvl = ? and user_id = ?

Comment: @Tomalak And I don't see how the DRY technique will fix everything by doing the exact same thing

Comment: Of course you don't see that, otherwise you would have written your code that way to begin with. I'm telling you *because* you don't see it. Organizing code is important. Preventing duplication equals preventing bugs. Anyway, your SQL is still wrong, and I can see that you have not verbalized what it actually does, only what you *think* it it is doing. (Hint: Manually add a couple of dummy user records to the DB and try again.)

Comment: @Tomalak If my SQL is wrong then tell me how to fix it. That's how StackOverflow works

Comment: @CrabbyFish UPDATE levels SET lvl = ? WHERE user_id = ?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson now it sets me to lvl 0

Comment: @CrabbyFish No, that's not how StackOverflow works. Stack Overflow works by making you learn. You've had a couple of days to stare at a single line of SQL that's missing a WHERE clause. It's not the only issue in your code, but the most prominent one and I pointed your nose right at It. Twice. It *should* have occurred to you by now. You also haven't done any of the other things I've asked of you (they all had a purpose), and instead decided to dump your entire code here and wait for someone who rewrites it for you. Sometimes this even happens, but it's not how Stak Overflow works.

Comment: @Tomalak Maybe i would learn if you told me what the damn mistake even is, because it cant be just me separating my code into helper functions, because I already tried that

Comment: Again (and for the last time now): I've told you to look very closely at the SQL. To verbalize what you think it does, and to compare it to what it actually does. To test it separately from your code. To check it for syntax problems. I've told you *twice*. You have not done that, you dismissed it outright. Hard to help you if you already know what's wrong and what's not wrong.

Comment: ...I've even told you exactly how to rewrite your code (the [DRY comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64951716/sqlite3-not-setting-fields-value-to-the-specified-value?noredirect=1#comment114834237_64951716)). The issue your code have would have become apparent immediately (and very probably the bug would not have occurred in the first place) if you had at least *tried*. But you haven't tried, because you already knew that that's not it. Well.

Comment: I have already given up and invited the MEE6 bot into my server, because if I didn't, I'd be having to deal with YOU